# SQL Update columns passing into the query the column name and value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET    Col1 = @Value
```

However, I have a table that has over a 100 columns and want to be able to specify a column name by passing the name into the query similar to:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET    @ColName = @Value
```

When I do this I get an error.  Is there a good solution to this?  Its probably something simple!

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to use dynamic SQL, and write it to make sure you don't let [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) in. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
SET @sql = N'UPDATE myTable SET ' + QUOTENAME(@colName) + ' = @pUpdateVal'
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @sql, '@pUpdateVal NVARCHAR(20)', @value
```

Make sure you change the type of @pUpdateVal to something appropriate for your environment, but this will mitigate the risk of injection attacks.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be UPDATE myTable?

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight ... yes :-) Fixed.

Comment: thanks, for everyone's comments and answers.  I created a Stored Procedure using dynamic SQL and worked a treat.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to revert to dynamic SQL to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with the others, you'll need dynamic SQL for this; you can't define object names at run time in native SQL.  For a full discussion on dynamic SQL see http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html